# Resolution troubles after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, xrandr will not add resolution

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

I upgraded last weekend, and my monitor (since long having run fine on 2560x1080_60.00) couldn´t get any higher 1920x1080. I tried adding a new resolution using `xrandr` but failed every time again.

A work around was returning to another kernel. Grub has available:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic
```

And returning to linux image: `/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic` helped me to get the higher resolution back into the settings menu.
With the newer kernel, it returned errors when trying to add `modeline` using `xrandr`.

I saw multiple questions on this, none of them (other than switching back to an older kernel) helped solve the problem.

Thanks and regards,
Bill

Comment: Have you tried both in Wayland and X?

Comment: Hi Sudodus, I did see the monitor as wayland0 pop up, but didn't recognise it. Can you please explain what I should have tried?

Comment: You can select between Wayland and X after clicking on the cog wheel according to the description in this link, https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/ and in this case I suggest that you try with X (alias Xorg alias `x11`).

Comment: in wayland xrandr will not work if you are using dual monitor go with the xorg from login screen otherwise go following link https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: xrandr will NOT work with Wayland !! https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution