# I am only offered one resolution for 17.10 Desktop running vanilla Gnome, why?

Tags: gnome, display, display-resolution

The install is direct on metal. I access this machine, which is remote, via Teamviewer 13. I have been using PC's for decades and never seen an OS expose only one resolution. Worse, at 1024x768, it is too low for practical use as many basic interface screens are larger than 1024x768.

Comment: Perhaps you need a driver for the graphics.

Comment: Welcome to wayland =) See https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: I tried two drivers. I tried Radeon-ati and Oibef. No change. Tried xrandr and editing grub. No change.17.10 is literally useless if it picks a single random sub panel resolution of the wrong aspect ratio.

Comment: No useful solution. I just reinstalled from scratch using a different version and release of base distro and a different sequence of updates/upgrades and configs. Now it offers me 4 or 5 resolutions, some higher/some lower.  But it is impossible to draw a conclusion as to why the situation is betterr this time around.