# Screen freezes when attempting changes in xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, radeon, display-resolution, xrandr

I am trying to use my external LCD display (BenQ V2200 Eco Specs) with my laptop (hp from about HP Compaq 6910 p with Lubuntu 17.10 with the latest updates).

When plugging the display while using monitor settings the screen stays black, no signal. When plugging it before booting, it runs but with the wrong resolution.

I believe `xrandr` is set in order to extend the desktop over both the laptop screen and the external LCD display, but the actual resolution on the LCD is 3200x1080 instead of 1920x1080, so the desktop is cropped on the right. The problem is that if I attempt any changes in the settings in `xrandr` or `arandr`, the screens freeze and I need to do a hard reboot. This also happens if I make changes without the external display being plugged in.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV516/M64-S [Mobility Radeon X2300]

$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

This is the output of xrandr (if I plug the display in the running computer; if I plug it before booting, current changes to 3200x1080):

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   1024x576      59.97  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
LVDS connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 190mm
   1280x800      60.00*+
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: So you want to use a particular resolution all the time ?

Comment: The only mode I can currently run is a resolution of 3200 x 1080 on the external lcd display, which has a native resolution of 1920 x 1080. So the displayed desktop is stretched beyond the screen boundary on the right. I want the resolution to be 1920 x 1080. The problem: if I make any (!) changes in xrandr, the screens freeze

Comment: Are you using wayland ? xrandr will not work with wayland.

Answer (score 4):

As you said when you plug the monitor before booting it gives a bad resolution, I believe adding a particular resolution in `.profile` would solve this issue.

Open the terminal and run the following command.

```
xrandr
```

[image: xrandr output]

Note the display device name from the output.In my case its eDP-1.

next run the following command

```
cvt 1920 1080
```

[image: command output in terminal]

Copy the whole Modeline from the output.

In my case it is as follows

```
"1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync.
```

And run the following command:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

NOTE the command sections after `--newmode` are copied from the output I got in the previous step.

Now add the newly created mode for your display device.

```
sudo xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Finally Apply the new resolution in the Display settings. Select the "1920x1080" resolution as your preferred resolution.

IMPORTANT: To make Ubuntu remember the new created screen resolution at next start, you have to edit your `.profile`. Use any text editor, for example:

```
vim ~/.profile
```

add the last 2 commands to the end

[image: profile in vim]

Save and reboot. Hopefully the system will detect `1920x1080` resolution in both your displays.

Comment: Nice work, but you do know xrandr will not work with wayland ? For wayland see https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your excellent reply. I was able to resolve the problem based on your advice and some more research:

I added the two additional comments to `.profile` as described by you. Additionally a third one, which changes the scale of the external display (I think neither `--dpi` nor `--panning` actually has an effect).

```
xrandr --dpi 102.3 --fb 3200x1080    --output VGA-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --panning 1920x1080 --scale 1.2x1
```

[This blog post](https://blog.summercat.com/configuring-mixed-dpi-monitors-with-xrandr.html) helped me figure it out.

I am not using Wayland.