# Portable monitor past monitor edges

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have an Asus monitor for a 2016 **XPS 13 developer edition** laptop.  I've been trying to get the resolution to look better than the defaults.  I ran the following xrandr commands:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Afterwared I changed the settings in the GUI manager.  The screen looks much better but the edges overflow past the monitor edges.  Is there a good way to fix this?  The monitor I am using is:

[https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-MB169B-1920x1080-Portable-Monitor/dp/B00FE690DI/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=portable%2Bmonitor&qid=1560014011&s=gateway&sr=8-3&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FE690DI)

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am running Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: You can't magically change the monitor's physical resolution of 1366x768 pixels to 1920x1080 pixels.

Comment: The Amazon link you provide is a bit ambiguous. Are you running the ASUS MB168B, or the ASUS MB168B+? The resolution of these monitors differs. Only the latter will support 1080p resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the auto adjust on your monitor by going to its menu and choosing: 
<kbd>LCD Monitor Troubleshooting</kbd> → <kbd>Picture or Text blur</kbd> → <kbd>Display Position or Resolution not correct</kbd> → <kbd>Screen color is abnormal or random jitter</kbd>

1. <kbd>Automatic calibration (Auto Adjust)</kbd>: Press and hold the <kbd>SPLENDID</kbd> key for about 4 seconds for automatic correction.

   **Note¹:**  <kbd>Auto Adjust</kbd> is valid only when the input is an analog signal (VGA).

   **Note²:** Not every model has an <kbd>Auto Adjust</kbd> hotkey.
2. Please adjust the current resolution to the correct setting and refresh rate according to the different sizes in the below table:

   ```
   Ratio   Size    Resolution   Refresh Rate
   ［4:3］      17"  1280x1024     60Hz  
   ［16:9］  23-46"  1920x1080     60Hz
              65"  1920x1080    120Hz  
   ［16:10］    20"  1680x1050     60Hz
              24": 1920x1200     60Hz
   ```
3. Update the graphic card driver:
   My monitor cannot display proper resolution
4. Monitor Reset: Back to the initial value of display:
   Hold down the <kbd>MENU</kbd> key and select <kbd>MENU</kbd> → <kbd>System Setup</kbd> → <kbd>Reset</kbd> → <kbd>Yes</kbd>
5. Check if the signal cable ( VGA / DVI / HDMI / DisplayPort / USB) is firmly seated and confirm the other end of the output cable has been firmly seated to the computer input port (graphics card). Unplug and plug 2-terminals again and make sure none of the pins are bent.

[Source](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013113/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to refer you to this answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/973582/307184

as anticipated, given the name "X" render, `xrandr` is incompatible with Wayland.

given Wayland is the default session on ubuntu 19.04 you cannot use `xrandr` (which is obsolete as 19.04 solves most to all display issues and comping with a more complete multi-monitor configurations menu built-in)

Basically your monitor is already at the correct resolution from a PC perspective and the only additional changes you can make must be found in the monitor setup itself (E.G. turn "overscan" off)

Comment: I assume in 19.04 you can change from Wayland to Xorg like you can in previous versions?

Comment: I suppose but I don't think you'd really want to : https://www.maketecheasier.com/whats-new-in-ubuntu-19-04/ this articale says there's no scaling for example with xorg.

Comment: You already said 90% of what I was going to say so **+1** and an edit but feel free to [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and/or revert the edit if you disagree with the addition.  **;-)**