# Laptop can't see external montior's maximum resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, wayland

I've got a Lenovo IdeaPad 5i 15IIL05 with Intel UHD graphics, running Ubuntu 20.04.1. I want to connect it to an external monitor (Acer Gaming Nitro VG270U) via HDMI.

When connected, it does work - however, the highest possible resolution the system suggests is 1920x1080, when the screen itself supports 2560 x 1440. It is definitely not a problem with a cable or the monitor itself - when connected to another laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 3gen with AMD Renoir iGPU), running Ubuntu 21.04, everything worked well.

I also don't think it is a problem with the installation itself. Before Ubuntu, this laptop was running Arch-based distro (Endeavour OS), where the same problem occurred.

Usually then facing some issues like this I'd start by checking what `xrandr` tells me about the screens connected. However, the laptop is running Wayland, so it doesn't work - and, as far as I know, there is no tool to replace it. I don't really know what can cause this issue. Here is some system information:

```
corny@warri:~$ lspci|grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a56 (rev 07)
```

```
corny@warri:/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1$ cat modes 
1920x1080
1920x1080
1920x1080
1920x1080i
1920x1080i
1920x1080
1920x1080i
1920x1080
1920x1080
1680x1050
1280x1024
1280x1024
1440x900
1280x960
1152x864
1280x720
1280x720
1280x720
1280x720
1280x720
1024x768
1024x768
1024x768
832x624
800x600
800x600
800x600
800x600
720x576
720x480
720x480
720x480
720x480
720x480
640x480
640x480
640x480
640x480
640x480
640x480
720x400
```

Where [is](https://superuser.com/questions/1137574/manually-add-a-resolution-to-gnome-with-wayland) also a suggestion of manually setting the resolution with `video` kernel boot parameter. However, I've tried several naming options (card0-HDMI-A-1, HDMI-A-1, HDMI-1), and it doesn't change anything - instead, it causes the internal screen to display some extremely glitched images.

I've also [seen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution) a suggestion to create custom edid and make the system use it. I haven't tried it (yet), however, I don't really see how that would help - if another laptop can "generate" valid EDID, this one should too.

What can I do in this situation? What can possibly cause such a problem?

Update: That is probably not a X11/Wayland issue - booting in X11 doesn't help, neither does adding custom resolution with `xrandr --newmode`.

Update: using custom EDID didn't help, either.

Comment: What happens when you switch from Wayland to x11? You can use the round icon at the bottom right corner of the log in screen of Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS to swiitch session type.

Comment: @sudodus that didn't change anything, sadly

Comment: Are you sure that the graphics chip/card can produce higher resolution than 1920x1080 via HDMI? That might be the bottleneck. Please check the specification for the graphics in a manual for the processor or the computer itself.

Comment: I do not think that chip set does what you want it to do.

Comment: @David it would be weird if relatively modern laptop wouldn't support 2K over HDMI. It has i5-1035G1, which, according to Intel specifications, supports up to 4096 x 2304@60Hz via HDMI 1.4. According to Lenovo, laptop's HDMI version is 1.4b, so that should be fine too.