# Ubuntu 21.04 - How to fix xrandr "X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)"

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr, vga

I have two identical HP monitors that both can handle 1920x1080 resolution connected to a basic HP SlimDesktop model 290-p0043w with a basic Intel® UHD Graphics 610 GPU. However, the video output is one HDMI and one VGA port.
I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed on the same computer before and after some tweaking I got the VGA port to work on 1920x1080 stable and reliable.
Now I installed Ubuntu 21.04 on the same computer and I do the following:

```
~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1920x1080_60.00"
~$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x780
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
~$
```

According to many web pages this (and Ubuntu help) it should be done this way. I also used **arandr** which only shows the newly added resolution, but when applying, it gives the same problem. I also did this (after a reboot) as sudo ... to the same avail.
Ubuntu -> Displays -> "Unknown Display" -> Resolution shows the standard 1024x768 as highest resolution.
I have seen many similar questions *(for other distro's as well)* but never any answer.

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: I had a similar problem and the modeline that I was using from `cvt` was wrong, in particular the pixel clock rate. Check the manual for your monitor.

Comment: @aryan did you figure it out? for such things I hate linux

Comment: It seems to be an issue with Wayland, as xrandr doesn't works with Wayland as with xorg.
Either you switch back to xorg, or follow the instructions there:
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out. In the the line:
[~$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1920x1080_60.00]
"XWAYLAND" is the name of the monitor (in this case the second) I changed it to "DP-2" and it worked. So now my line looks like:
[~$ xrandr --addmode DP-2 "1920x1080_60.00"]

This could be different for you, so you have to experiment a bit to find out what your distro says the second monitor is named.

Good luck.