# Wayland how to set a custom resolution that works for Gnome

Tags: display-resolution

I just upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10. Previously I have to rely on using xrandr to set the screen resolution to 1280x1024@60Hz because I have a old Logix monitor.

I tried https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution/ and all I got was the boot up screen appeared to be in the right resolution (Ubuntu 21.10 ...) but the screen reverted to 1024x768 when the login screen appears.

Is there a better and successful way to force the resolution?

Comment: It is possible that you need X (instead of Wayland) in order to make things work with your old monitor. And it is easy to switch: Press the round icon at the bottom right corner of the log in screen of newer Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Interesting that it worked in the GDM screen. It should then be possible in your user account as well. But as sudodus indicated, you could just switch to xorg instead, but of course, it is interesting to find the solution with Wayland.

Comment: Solution here worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1210275/196546