# Kubuntu 22.04.1 on an Oracle 7.0 VM box

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox, xubuntu, java, oracle

I have an Oracle VM 7.0 with 4 Ubuntu OSs on it, and the last one I put on there is a Kubuntu 22.04.1, and I cannot get the size of the display I would like. The other 3 are Xubuntu 22.04.1, the Ubuntu 22.04.01, and the Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1.
They all offer 2580 x 1440 except for the Kubuntu,and the Kubuntu only goes to 1920 x 1440 with no other larger sizes available. I found an older article that said that we could type in the terminal for a certain program download, but it was outdated and my terminal said that it could not find it. I would appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: I would contrast your settings or configuration differences between Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS & Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, as both use the same KDE Plasma desktop.  Are there differences there as those are pretty similar, though as Kubuntu uses a `ubiquity` installer it can install differently to Ubuntu Studio's use of `calamares` (though Xubuntu & Ubuntu Desktop itself also use `ubiquity`).

Comment: I am not sure about the ubiquity and calamares, as I am relatively new to all of this. The KDE Plasma is recognizable to me though, I will see if I can tell the differences in the actual installs, especially the Xubuntu. I know I can get the other 3 to fill Omen 27i monitor, and the Kubuntu is about the size I use for the browsers on my Widow 11 system  (1920 x 1440).

Comment: Sorry; `ubiquity` is the name of the installer used by most *flavors* (but not Lubuntu & Ubuntu Studio) & `calamares` the installer used by the other two.  In a way I was thinking aloud, but there are some differences that `ubiquity` is capable of but `calamares` isn't (relating to kernel stack choice inc. OEM options). As for kernel stack choices; I'd look at `uname -a` for clues as to what you're using; differences there but I'm '*reaching*' there as I can't think of differences (Ubuntu Studio tries to offer low-latency but is stuck with what `calamares` allows..)

Comment: Thank you @guiverc, even though it's just thinking out loud, it may help, who knows!!! I will definitely check that out, and hope I can learn something lol!!!

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the VM not telling KDE the right resolution? Or, maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/1210275/29073 helps? I've not done this sort of thing since xrandr was the thing to use and Wayland doesn't work with that AFAIK.

Comment: What is AFAIK @pbhj?
But you did give me an idea, I'll go back through the VM settings and see.
So far I have found nothing to change that resolution, short of uninstalling that desktop and installing the one from Lubuntu or something lol, gotta learn this stuff sooner or later! Thank you for the suggestions, all of you! If/when I figure it out I will post it here.

Comment: As Far As I Know.

Comment: Just for information, I totally appreciate the answers; however, due to my Widows OS I wound up with the VM deleted, so it was no longer an issue. I restarted it with only two of the Linux systems on it at the moment, Ubuntu 22.04 and the UbuntuStudio 22.04, I really like these two. Next will be the sound issue, lol. VM has terrible sound. Thank you all!!!