# Trying to add 1920x1280 mode "out of range" error

Tags: display, display-resolution

Testing kubuntu from usb stick. Single, wired, Viewsonic 14415 monitor. I use the following commands to add 1920x1280 mode:

> cvt 1920 1280

> xrandr --newmode "1920x1280_60.00"  206.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1280 1283 1293 1327 -hsync +vsync

> xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1280_60.00"

No errors with any of that, and the 1920x1280 mode shows up on the Display Settings screen. When I try using this mode I get the "out of range" error from the monitor. This is the resolution I use on windows with no problems.
Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 1920x1080 resolution fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504000/no-1920x1080-resolution-fix)